# SSRS and PowerBI Report Server on same server

Tags: ssrs-2016, powerbi-report-server

I've just installed the August 2018 release of PowerBI Report Server onto the same Win 2012 server with SSRS 2016. I can get it running but it clashes with SSRS with URL reservations.

I've configured them to use different Virtual directories and ports but SSRS keeps breaking.

- SSRS: http://ServerName:80/Reports
- PBIRS:  http://ServerName:8080/PBIReports

What have I missed?

Edit: I have SSRS 2017 and PBIRS working at the same time on my laptop. Both on Port 80 but with different virtual directories.

Comment: You can either have powerBI or ssrs on a given server.

Comment: @Kin. I have SSRS 2017 and Power BI Report Server both successfully running simultaneoulsy on my Win 10 laptop. Why can't I have both on a Win 2012 server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I now have this working on my Win-2012 server with PBIRS (August 2018) and SSRS 2016.

First they need to have thier own ReportServer Databases. I used:

- SSRS: ReportServer
- PBIRS:  PBIReportServer

The Webservice URL's use the same port number but different Virtual directories.

- SSRS: http://ServerName:80/ReportServer
- PBIRS:  http://ServerName:80/PBIReportServer

And the Webportal again uses the same port number, but different URLS.

- SSRS: http://ServerName:80/Reports
- PBIRS:  http://ServerName:80/PBIReports

And so far it seems to be behaving. I've restarted the server and both services started automatically and appear to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used PowerBI report server, but you're missing one component of the SSRS installation.  The /Reports folder is the Web location (aka the "Web Portal URL" in the SSRS Configuration manager), but it points to a /ReportServer App location (aka the "Web Service URL" in the SSRS Configuration Manager).  Is the PowerBI report server pointing to the same /ReportServer port/location?

Comment: On the server they are using different ports for reportserver. On my laptop they are the same.

Comment: The issue was that the URL needed to share the same port, rather than compete with different ones (which I thought i needed to keep them separate). But you were close so I'll give you a +1 for effort ;)