# Migrate SSRS Reports to Power BI Report Server

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2016, powerbi-report-server

I have to servers: one with the SSRS Report Server and a second server with the Power BI Report Server.

The issue is I'm trying to migrate the SSRS Reports to the Power BI Report Server instance on a third server that I plan to unify both report databases.

As far as I understood based on a Microsoft article (**[Migrate a report server installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/migrate-report-server)**), it's possible to migrate the SSRS database to the Power BI Report Server as shown in the picture to the same instance and service (Power BI Report Server in this case):

[image: Migrating to Power BI Report Server from SSRS (Native mode)]

I've created the backup of the SSRS databases (and encryption key) and restored on the PBI server, but it's not working. If I restore only the PBI database (and its encryption key) it works fine on the destination server. On the Report Server Configuration Manager I can only set the ReportServerPBI (that I restored from the server that already runs the PBI) to have it working. If I set the ReportServer database that I've had made the backup it doesn't work.

Am I mistaken or is there any way that I can put these services in the same server/database and running under the Power BI Report Server?

Will I have to keep separate instances to have both dashboard types running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...is there any way that I can put these services in the same 
>   server/database and running under the Power BI Report Server?

[You can have SSRS and PBIRS on the same *Server*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217741/ssrs-and-powerbi-report-server-on-same-server/219134), but they will require their own ReportServer databases in order to run them both.

If you want to migrate your SSRS reports into PBIRS, then you need to follow the steps in the MS article. 1. Restore a copy of the SSRS database to a new server, and then 2. *install* PBI RS. PBI RS will update the database and retain the reports within it.

I think the article gets a little confusing as most people reading it will be migrating from SSRS to PBIRS on a different SQL Server. There isn't a lot of info about running both side by side. But it can be done.

Comment: I did restore the SSRS databases into a server with the Power BI Report Server, restored the encryption key, but when I open the SSRS URL it says something went wrong. Do you have any idea what's happening?
I checked permissions and everything seems to be OK.

Comment: Did you overwrite the ReportServer Db that PowerBi was using? Or restore it to a different name?>

Comment: I restored a ReportServer (with its respective TempDB) database that was alteady on the server with the one that is being used by another instance of SSRS. I did the same with the ReportServerPBI database and it's working.

Comment: So its resolved then? Well done.

Comment: It's working only on separate databases, not as the Microsoft's article suggests it would work in the same database. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Update: I managed to publish SSRS reports into PBI Report Server and it's working. Worked the same way it works on SSRS - create a data source, a dataset and then publish the report.